# Vertically centering text in HTML table cell in Java JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, vertical-alignment

I have an HTML table (styles with CSS) that is displayed in a JLabel. I would like the contents (a single, short line of text) of the cells to be both horizontally and vertically centered. Horizontal centering is easy, but I cannot seem to center the text vertically. I've tried `vertical-align:` and `valign:` with both `middle` and `center` arguments. I've looked at several of the tricks, but none of them seemed doable, and the ones I tried didn't work.

What I have now:

Inline (in the `<style>` tag) CSS:

```
table.outer {
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:none;
}

td.outer {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1pt;
    border-color:#888888;
    padding:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;
}

table.inner {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:none;
}

td.title {
    width:75pt;
    background:#BFBFBF;
    padding:1.5pt 0pt 1.5pt 0pt;
}
```

The relevant portion of the HTML:

```
<body bgcolor=#F0F0F0>
<table class='outer'>
  <tr>
    <td class='outer' valign=top>
    <table class='inner'>
      <tr>
        <td class='title' rowspan=3>
          <p class='title'>Current Run</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for [*HTML in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) is [limited](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) to [3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32), but `valign="middle"` should work.