# How to make my webbrowser able to use JavaScript in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, swing, mozilla, chromium

In my Java web browser, the javascript alert() is not working how to make it active?

Example:

```
package www;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

public class HtmlEditorKitTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HtmlEditorKitTest();
  }

  public HtmlEditorKitTest() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
        jEditorPane.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jEditorPane);
        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        jEditorPane.setEditorKit(kit);
        StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
        styleSheet.addRule("body {color:#000; font-family:times; margin: 4px; }");
        styleSheet.addRule("h1 {color: blue;}");
        styleSheet.addRule("h2 {color: #ff0000;}");
        styleSheet.addRule("pre {font : 10px monaco; color : black; background-color : #fafafa; }");
        String htmlString = "<html>\n"
                          + "<body>\n"
                          + "<script>alert('Show Javascript works or not');</script>\n"
                          + "<h1>Welcome!</h1>\n"
                          + "<h2>H2 header</h2>\n"
                          + "<p>Text description</p>\n"
                          + "<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com/can/whynot?Oracle?/\">SiteOpen</a></p>\n"
                          + "</body>\n";

        Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
        jEditorPane.setDocument(doc);
        jEditorPane.setText(htmlString);
        JFrame j = new JFrame("WebBrowser in Java");
        j.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        j.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "web browser"? your JFrame?

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6785121/230513).

Comment: I think this is relevant too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling something a web browser doesn't make it a web browser.

From the [`HTMLEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) API:

> The Swing JEditorPane text component supports different kinds of content via a plug-in mechanism called an EditorKit. Because HTML is a very popular format of content, some support is provided by default. The default support is provided by this class, which supports HTML version 3.2 (with some extensions), and is migrating toward version 4.0. The `<applet>` tag is not supported, but some support is provided for the `<object>` tag.

Comment: After making a functional applet context and environment, I went to add support for the `applet` element in the editor kit of a `JEditorPane` (for use in [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/)).  I achieved it, but it was the *toughest part of the entire process.*