# html files encryption for client side

Tags: java, swing, lucene, swingutilities

I am using lucene for indexing and searching on client side after searching the keyword i want to display the html files there . So is there any way to store and access the html files . actually the html files are storing images and links and they should be opened in the java api as normal html file .
I am using the following code for lucene indexing

```
  try
  {

        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(

        FSDirectory.open(indexDir),

        new SimpleAnalyzer(),

        true,
        IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
        indexWriter.setUseCompoundFile(false);
        indexDirectory(indexWriter, dataDir, suffix);

        Document doc = new Document();

        doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f))); 

        doc.add(new Field("filename",f.getCanonicalPath(),

        Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);

        numIndexed = indexWriter.maxDoc();

        indexWriter.optimize();

        indexWriter.close();

        } 

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

How should i display the html files matching the search criteria on client side

Comment: As written (and even after edits), your question is indecipherable. What HTML files? How are these files added to Lucene, and where are they stored? Are you talking about a desktop (Swing) client, or a web client? Does the client have access to the original files?

Comment: My recommendation is that you step back and draw out a block diagram of your application, and then ask your question again. And unless that code is somehow specific to your question (it looks like generic code to add a document to a Lucene index), just remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for [`browse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29), which "Launches the default browser to display a URI."  Alternatively, an [editor pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) can be used, although support is [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6785121/230513).

Comment: @David: I have trouble thinking outside the (trash) can. :-)