# HTML in java JFrame?

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jeditorpane

I have searched it on the net , but only solution I found out is JEditorPane , with the suggestion to not to use it , as it is very weak. Is there not any other alternative, other than JEditorPane ?

Comment: With saying how HTML support in `JEditorPane` fails to meet your requirements, this question is not constructive.

Comment: Check out JavaFX: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

Comment: @trashgod: the problems with JEditorPAne are really well known, beginning with it not using style sheets.

Comment: @Traroth While I agree with you, I think Trashgod's point is that not explaining what the missing requirements are makes it impossible to answer the question with out significant guess work

Comment: @Traroth: I can't disagree, but the question says _nothing_ about what would constitute a better alternative for some particular use case. Edit: more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12680496/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for HTML in `JEditorPane` is [limited](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html). I would say use `JWebPane`, but somehow the project seems to be at a stop. Try Flying Saucer if you need portability:

http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

or if native code is ok, you can try the DJ Project:

http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/

Comment: +1 for context and alternatives.

Comment: Needless to say, nowadays using JavaFX's javafx.scene.web.WebView (which is actually the achieved version of JWebPane) would be the best solution. Flying Saucer and DJ Project seem both to be obsolete.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31722598/230513).