# JEditorPane using getPage() method for webpage

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

I have problem with getPage() method when i use it for JEditorPane , it dose not display a web page correctly and dose not suport every thing , means i want to display every thing like chrome and other browser. here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class browser extends JFrame {
    private JTextField addressbar;
    private JEditorPane display;
    public browser(){
        super("web browser");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        addressbar=new JTextField("Enter URL");
        addressbar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                loadCrap(event.getActionCommand());
            }
        });

        add(addressbar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        display=new JEditorPane();
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener(){
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event){
                if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED){
                    loadCrap(event.getURL().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        add(new JScrollPane(display),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    private void loadCrap(String Address){
        try{
            display.setPage(Address);
            addressbar.setText(Address);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("crap !");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new browser();
    }

}
```

Comment: HTML support is [limited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6785121/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Desktop` class to display webpages. See the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more information and working examples.